# pip install issue with ssl certificate:[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED]

Tags: python, pip, installation, ssl-certificate, access-denied

Pip version:9.0.1
Python version:3.6.3
Operating system:Win7

**Description:**
I'm trying to install python libraries in my laptop but run into an SSL certificate error when running pip -install for any library. I have tried several suggestions from other posts but all of them didn't work. 
Can someone kindly help me to resolve this SSL issue? Thanks in advance.

**What I've run:**

```
C:\Users\zhouweiq>pip install requests
Collecting requests
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_ACCESS_DENIED] tlsv1 alert access denied (_ssl.c:777) - skipping  
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

Comment: did you solve the problem? I'm having a very similar one

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I also got the same issue but after configuring proxy it resolved.
Proxy in Windows-> internet options-> connections -> LAN settings.